# Complicated rules for mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

creating correct instructions for mod_rewrite. It seems to be very difficult.

I need exactly the following:

1. **Redirect** from `www.example.com` to `example.com`.

   - `www.example.com/hello`                ==>     `example.com/hello`
   - `www.example.com/abc/def`              ==>     `example.com/abc/def`

   etc., and then other rules should be applied.
2. Direct access (no rewrite) to some specified files and folders (such as **`robots.txt`, images/**, etc.)

   Maybe

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(robots.txt|favicon.ico|images|documents|~.\*)
   ```

   Am I right?
   So, URLs like

   - `example.com/robots.txt`               ==>     `example.com/robots.txt`
   - `example.com/documents/file1.pdf`      ==>     `example.com/documents/file1.pdf`

   should remain as is and shouldn't be rewritten.
3. Another transformation:

   - `example.com/index.php?anythinghere`   ==>     `example.com/a/index.php?anythinghere`
4. But if we type URLs `example.com` and `example.com/` Apache should call `index.php` in the root folder (`example.com/index.php`)

   `example.com`                         ==>     `example.com/index.php`
   `example.com/`                         ==>     `example.com/index.php`
5. I have MVC script, and if we type the following URLs:

   1. `example.com/controller` or `example.com/controller/` or `example.com/controller//`
   2. `example.com/controller/function` or `example.com/controller/function/`
   3. `example.com/controller/function/parameter or example.com/controller/function/param1/param2/param3

   **and** if controller is one of predefined words in the list, say, "index", "news", "contacts" (maybe it will be expanded up to few hundreds of words), then we should call `index.php`, rewriting URLs the following way:

- `example.com/controller`               ==>     `example.com/index.php?q=controller`
- `example.com/controller/`              ==>     `example.com/index.php?q=controller/`
- `example.com/controller//`             ==>     `example.com/index.php?q=controller//`
- `example.com/controller/function`      ==>     `example.com/index.php?q=controller/function`
- `example.com/controller/function/`     ==>     `example.com/index.php?q=controller/function/`
- `example.com/controller/function/parameter`              ==>  `example.com/index.php?q=controller/function/parameter`
- `example.com/controller/function/param1/param2/param3`    ==>  `example.com/index.php?q=controller/function/param1/param2/param3`

6. And, finally, if all previous rules weren't applied, we should rewrite

- `example.com/anythinghere`             ==>     `example.com/a/index.php?anythinghere`

Hope Apache doesn't use mod_rewrite recursively, or I will have huge troubles with different `index.php`s.

Comment: I've edited a bit your question in order to make more clear the transformations. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **first** rewrite, you can put these lines in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301]
```

It's very important to put `R=301` in order to make it a permanent redirect, so that search engines won't see `www.site.com` and `site.com` as two different sites.

For the **second** rewrite many options are available. Perhaps will be more useful for you to make apache serve all the files that actually exist (such as images and pdf documents) and to rewrite those URLs that mean some MVC commands.

If you think so, you can cover your **fifth** rewrite, and write this:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^/news$ ./index.php?news  [L]
RewriteRule ^/news/(.*)$ ./index.php?news/$1  [L]
```

And so on for each `controller` you have. If you plan to have hundreds of controllers, then I think you should rethink the design of your system, or make them subcontrollers of a few main controllers, so these main controller can be written in this `.htaccess` file.

Also important is `L`, which tells apache it is the last line executed (last one if matched the condition), so you avoid recursion (among other things if I remember well).

To cover the **third** one:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php?(.*)$ ./a/index.php?$1  [L]
```

To cover the **sixth** and last one:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ ./a/index.php?$1  [L]
```

---

So, covering the rewrites 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6 we can have:

```
RewriteEngine On

# First rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301]

# Second and fifth rewrite
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^/news$ ./index.php?news  [L]
RewriteRule ^/news/(.*)$ ./index.php?news/$1  [L]

# Third rewrite
RewriteRule ^/index.php?(.*)$ ./a/index.php?$1  [L]

# Sixth rewrite
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ ./a/index.php?$1  [L]
```

Comment: I have no access to my development server right now, so I haven't been able to test these rules yet.